# LiveCD not showing welcome page

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, live-cd

When I boot from the Live CD instead of the welcome screen with the buttons "Try" and "Install" and the language selection a weird GRUB appears with the options "Try without installing", "Install Ubuntu", etc. IN ENGLISH. I'm Spanish, so I want to try Ubuntu in Spanish. If I select "Try without installing" in this weird GRUB the Ubuntu live trial starts as usual IN ENGLISH. If I want to install Ubuntu, it has to be in english too. How can I go to the welcome page and select my language? Why a weird GRUB is showing when I boot from my LiveCD?

Using a 14.04L LTS LiveCD in a PC with Windows 8. I can boot from the CD, so Secure Boot or UEFI isn't the problem.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If you select try without installing, Ubuntu will boot from the CD into an environment you can use. From there, there should be a shortcut on the desktop that will let you install Ubuntu, and in that menu you can select the language you want to install with.